# How do I launch jupyter notebook from my terminal?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Trying to Launch jupyter notebook from terminal. I am currently on my terminal in the correct folder, and I have python 3.5 installed along with conda. But it is not launching.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Jupyter Notebooks allow you to open `IPYNB` notebooks in the location you prefer. I generally recommend the following:

1. First create a folder at your preferred destination
2. Then go to terminal/cmd prompt and navigate to your above made destination
3. Once in the destination then type in `jupyter notebook`

This will then automatically trigger the browser and open the Home tab, you can start a new notebook with your preferred kernel, rename and save the notebook, which it saves at the location where you navigated through the terminal

This helps you organize your relevant/related notebooks in the same place in a structured manner.

Example shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In the terminal and in the folder where your `ipynb` file is located, enter:

```
jupyter notebook NAMEOFFILE.ipynb
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me when I try with a specific file: it opens on browser a URL of type `file:///tmp/tmpuchfjlw0.html` and nothing happens. With directories it worked though. Tested on `notebook==6.5.3`.

Comment: Works for me.  Jupyter Server 2.7.3

Answer (score 5):

Just type the command in the terminal to open the jupyter notebook.

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
~/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook --port 8887
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34867534)