# conda environment path is different for ipython versus jupyter

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am using the `conda` environment manager and created a new environment `borehole` for a new project. However that paths for `jupyter lab` are different than for the `ipython` interactive terminal. Here is the `jupyter lab` path:

[image]

To confirm this, we can also see that the jupyterlab extension is coming from the env borehole directory:

[image]

And this is the `ipython` path:

[image]

In this `jupyter lab` case, all of the paths link to a different environment called `faroe`.  However in the `ipython` case they link to the correct environment, `borehole`. What is more, if we look at the path to the commands, all of them link to the correct path `borehole`:

[image]

The ultimate problem here is that the packages installed in the environment cannot be referenced by the jupyter notebooks since the path for the jupyter notebooks is different from the environment the jupyter notebook server is installed in.

Below is the requirements file

```
# packages in environment at /home/john/anaconda3/envs/borehole:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       1_gnu    conda-forge
_py-xgboost-mutex         2.0                       cpu_0    conda-forge
alsa-lib                  1.2.3                h516909a_0    conda-forge
anyio                     3.2.0            py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py38h497a2fe_2    conda-forge
async_generator           1.10                       py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
babel                     2.9.1              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
bleach                    3.3.0              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h497a2fe_1001    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.17.1               h7f98852_1    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2021.5.30            ha878542_0    conda-forge
cartopy                   0.19.0.post1     py38hc9c980b_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2021.5.30        py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.5           py38ha65f79e_0    conda-forge
chardet                   4.0.0            py38h578d9bd_1    conda-forge
conda                     4.10.1           py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
conda-package-handling    1.7.3            py38h497a2fe_0    conda-forge
cryptography              3.4.7            py38ha5dfef3_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_2    conda-forge
dbus                      1.13.6               h48d8840_2    conda-forge
decorator                 5.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3             pyhd8ed1ab_1003    conda-forge
expat                     2.4.1                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.1            hba837de_1005    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h0708190_1    conda-forge
future                    0.18.2           py38h578d9bd_3    conda-forge
geos                      3.9.1                h9c3ff4c_2    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          h0b5b191_1005    conda-forge
glib                      2.68.3               h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.68.3               h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
greenlet                  1.1.0            py38h709712a_0    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.18.4               hf529b03_2    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.18.4               h76c114f_2    conda-forge
icu                       68.1                 h58526e2_0    conda-forge
idna                      2.10               pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        4.5.0            py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 5.5.5            py38hd0cf306_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.24.1           py38hd0cf306_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ipywidgets                7.6.3              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
jbig                      2.1               h7f98852_2003    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.0           py38h578d9bd_2    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
joblib                    1.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9d                   h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.5              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0            py38h578d9bd_6    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.12             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.7.1            py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server            1.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                3.0.16             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         2.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.3.1            py38h1fd1430_1    conda-forge
krb5                      1.19.1               hcc1bbae_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.12                 hddcbb42_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.35.1               hea4e1c9_2    conda-forge
lerc                      2.2.1                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libclang                  11.1.0          default_ha53f305_1    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.77.0               h2574ce0_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.7                  h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h516909a_1    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.10               hcdb4288_3    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  h58526e2_2    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 9.3.0               h2828fa1_19    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            9.3.0               hff62375_19    conda-forge
libgfortran5              9.3.0               hff62375_19    conda-forge
libglib                   2.68.3               h3e27bee_0    conda-forge
libgomp                   9.3.0               h2828fa1_19    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 h516909a_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libllvm11                 11.1.0               hf817b99_2    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.43.0               h812cca2_0    conda-forge
libogg                    1.3.4                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.15          pthreads_h8fe5266_1    conda-forge
libopus                   1.3.1                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h21135ba_2    conda-forge
libpq                     13.3                 hd57d9b9_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h36c2ea0_1    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.9.0                ha56f1ee_6    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              9.3.0               h6de172a_19    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.3.0                hf544144_1    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.32.1            h7f98852_1000    conda-forge
libvorbis                 1.3.7                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.0                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h7f98852_1003    conda-forge
libxgboost                1.4.0                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libxkbcommon              1.0.3                he3ba5ed_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.12               h72842e0_0    conda-forge
libxslt                   1.1.33               h15afd5d_2    conda-forge
lxml                      4.6.3            py38hf1fe3a4_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.0.1            py38h497a2fe_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.4.2            py38hcc49a3a_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py38h497a2fe_1003    conda-forge
mysql-common              8.0.25               ha770c72_2    conda-forge
mysql-libs                8.0.25               hfa10184_2    conda-forge
nbclassic                 0.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
nbclient                  0.5.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 6.0.7            py38h578d9bd_3    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.2                  h58526e2_4    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
notebook                  6.4.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
nspr                      4.30                 h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
nss                       3.67                 hb5efdd6_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.20.3           py38h9894fe3_1    conda-forge
obspy                     1.2.2            py38h5c078b8_1    conda-forge
olefile                   0.46               pyh9f0ad1d_1    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.4.0                hb52868f_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1k               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
packaging                 20.9               pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.14.0.2             h7f98852_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.45                 h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    8.2.0            py38ha0e1e83_1    conda-forge
pip                       21.1.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
proj                      7.2.0                h277dcde_2    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.19             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            3.0.19               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h36c2ea0_1001    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
py-xgboost                1.4.0            py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
pycosat                   0.6.3           py38h497a2fe_1006    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.20               pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pygments                  2.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.12.3           py38h578d9bd_7    conda-forge
pyqt-impl                 5.12.3           py38h7400c14_7    conda-forge
pyqt5-sip                 4.19.18          py38h709712a_7    conda-forge
pyqtchart                 5.12             py38h7400c14_7    conda-forge
pyqtwebengine             5.12.1           py38h7400c14_7    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.17.3           py38h497a2fe_2    conda-forge
pyshp                     2.1.3              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38h578d9bd_3    conda-forge
python                    3.8.10          h49503c6_1_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.8                      1_cp38    conda-forge
pytz                      2021.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     22.1.0           py38h2035c66_0    conda-forge
qt                        5.12.9               hda022c4_4    conda-forge
qtconsole                 5.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.1                  h46c0cb4_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.25.1             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
ruamel_yaml               0.15.80         py38h497a2fe_1004    conda-forge
scikit-learn              0.24.2           py38hdc147b9_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.6.3            py38h7b17777_0    conda-forge
send2trash                1.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
setuptools                49.6.0           py38h578d9bd_3    conda-forge
shapely                   1.7.1            py38haeee4fe_5    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sniffio                   1.2.0            py38h578d9bd_1    conda-forge
sqlalchemy                1.4.18           py38h497a2fe_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.36.0               h9cd32fc_0    conda-forge
terminado                 0.10.1           py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             2.1.0              pyh5ca1d4c_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               h21135ba_1    conda-forge
tornado                   6.1              py38h497a2fe_1    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.61.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.0.5                      py_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.5             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
websocket-client          0.57.0           py38h578d9bd_4    conda-forge
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1            py38h578d9bd_4    conda-forge
xgboost                   1.4.0            py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h516909a_1    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                h516909a_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
zipp                      3.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h516909a_1010    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.0                ha95c52a_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: Can you confirm jupyter was launched from borehole environment's terminal?

Comment: Yes through the where command but is there another way?

Comment: step1. open the terminal as that of 3rd image
step2. type jupyter notebook
step3. import sys and sys.path

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549723/how-do-i-launch-jupyter-notebook-from-my-terminal

Comment: That's the output shown in the first image

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the setup. if output of conda list -n borehole contains jupyter then it should be able to reference packages installed in borehole's environment. you just need to ensure that you have launched the jupyter from that environment.

Comment: yes see my added image. the jupyter server comes from the borehole environment.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to install [nb_conda_kernels](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels) which then provides all the kernels to jupyter lab.